# Asset pipeline in namespace, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I have split my app up into two part: A website part, and a /admin-part, with seperate javascripts and stylesheets.

I have converted all my admin plugins to fit this structure:

```
vendor/assets/ADMIN/mws
|-- index.js
|-- images/
|    |-- <various button/gradient images>
|-- javascripts/
|    |-- mws.js
|-- stylesheets/
|    |-- mws-buttons.css
|        mws-horizontal.css
```

vendor/assets/ADMIN/mws/index.js:

```
//= require mws
//= require_tree .
```

In my layout-file:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "admin/mws" %>
```

^ this gives a 404 pointing to http://127.0.0.1:3000/assets/admin/mws.js

```
rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.2)
1.9.3p125 :001 > Rails.application.config.assets.paths
=> ["/Users/me/Projects/rails-project/vendor/assets/admin"]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is the directory really upper case like that?  or did you do that for emphasis?

Answer (score 2):

You want the manifest in the javascript_include_tag so in your case

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'admin/index' %>
```

I don't think the

//= require mws

Is correct

Comment: This is right - except `//= require mws` is valid if he wants to load the mws script before all the rest in the tree.  If you want to load ONLY mws.js as a separate file, you'll need to add it as a separate file for the asset pipeline to compile.